# why $x \in \mathbb{Q}^c ?$

Tags: general-topology

i have some confusion  in sorgenfrey line, my doubt is marked in red line and red box given below

[image]

My Doubts : we know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and $\mathbb{Q}^c$ is uncountable

Here we have already  assume that $( S,T)$ has a  countable basis , then why $x \in \mathbb{Q}^c$ ?

From my point of view it should be $V= \{( x-1, x] : x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Comment: For an arbitrary basis $\mathcal A$ it is proved that it has an uncountable subcollection $\hat{\mathcal A}$. This implies that $\mathcal A$ itself must be uncountable. So this proves that no countable basis exists, q.e.d..

Comment: @drhab  in the proof  ,arbitrary basis was not taken

Comment: I admit that the proof is a bit weird. I would have done it like this: "Let $\mathcal A$ be an arbitrary basis. We will prove now that $\mathcal A$ is uncountable...et cetera." Their way looks a bit like this: "Let $\mathcal A$ be a countable basis. We will prove now that $\mathcal A$ is uncountable. Then a contradiction is found showing that no countable basis exists." Actually they use "reductio ad absurdum" and I think that in this case that is only complicating things.

Comment: @drhab another bad sign: he starts with "suppose $f$ is not injective" and then gets a contradiction from "$f$ is injective". Why not show from the outset that $f$ is injective. No need for a proof from contradiction here. The author has a "fetish" for proofs from contradiction, even if they're not needed, actually. Just do: given any base we find a subfamily of size continuum in it. Done.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes you are absolutely right! I did not dive deep enough into the proof to see that "miskleun".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $x \in \Bbb Q^\complement$ is in fact unnecessary. The author could just as well have considered $V=\{(x-1,x]: x \in \Bbb R\}$ instead. We then have, as $\mathcal{A}$ is *some* base for the Sorgenfrey line, and $(x-1,x]$ is open in that topology and $x$ is in it, that there is some $A_x \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $$x \in A_x \subseteq (x-1,x] .$$ Then if $x < y$, $y \notin A_x$ (as $A_x$ lies to the left of $x$), but $y \in A_y$, so $A_x \neq A_y$. So the assignment $x \to A_x$ is a 1-1 mapping from $\Bbb R$ into $\mathcal{A}$, and as $\mathcal{A}$ is any base for the Sorgenfrey line, any base of that space is uncountable, which proves the assertion. The fact that $x$ is in $\Bbb Q$ or not is completely irrelevant.

Don't let it distract you from the core of the argument, which is what I just repeated.

Comment: IMV "just as well" can be changed into "better". The posted question is a confirmation of that.

Comment: @drhab agreed. The author had another argument in mind maybe but changed it later or so it seems to me. The argument I gave is the “book proof” I think (as Erdös might have put it).

Comment: thanks u sir @HennoBrandsma